# Preventing label text from overlapping in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, labeling, maplex

Using ArcGIS 10.1 Desktop of Home Use (ArcInfo license I believe), I'm getting results like this using the included Maplex labelling engine:

[image]

Placement is curved. [Try horizontal position first box is unchecked.]

Strategy order for fitting is:

- Stack Label - default settings
- Reduce label in size - Font is 12 pt Arial, lower limit set to 1 pts, step interval is 1.1 pts.  Font Width compression is at default (90% lower limit & 5% step interval).
- Abbreviate Label - not enabled
- Overrun feature - not enabled
- Compress label in width - not sure if this enabled or not.

The region "Steamboat - Hilltop 16" is properly labeled.  As long as the entirety of that text is within the polygon in question I don't care how it might be stacked.

The region "Steamboat - Mountain 17" (directly below Hilltop 16 and to the left) is incorrectly labeled.  It has written the "- 17" underneath the Mountain and is unreadable.

This didn't happen using Maplex in ArcGIS 10.  Is there anyway to stop this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like a question for ESRI Support.

Answer (score 2):

Try adjusting/editing the text properties.  Try increasing the leading values. It's always set to zero as default. Set it to 1 or 2 and see what happens. I have not used Maplex engine for some time however; when labelling normally I often use "Leading" in the text properties because it nicely separates stacked text. (Layer Properties/Symbol/Formatted Text)

In the maplex label engine, there might be something you can change for the Stack Label. You have it set to default... try playing with switching the settings.